# Is time complexity for training a model not significant in deep learning publications?

Tags: journals, publishability, machine-learning

In computer science, in general, the time complexity is one of the important features to be checked before publishing a research paper in a journal.

I am confused about this in deep learning. If I am able to design a model that can outperform the existing architectures for a particular task on some metrics, then is it enough for publishing a paper in deep learning without mentioning anything about the time taken for training?

I got this doubt because of the following reason:

Many research papers in several other domains in computer science generally mention the running time. But when I started reading the research papers in deep learning, the key focus is on the architecture and other hyperparameters, but not on the time complexity. There can be exceptions, but I am asking this question regarding general consensus on publishability in the deep learning research community.

Comment: Besides other things, it's almost always the same for deep learning and is roughly cubic (or, with common matrix multiplication algorithm like [Strassen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm), closer to $O(n^{2.8})$) - only the constant varies... [More info](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20281).

Comment: You guys should feel free to refer any questions like this (machine learning models) to [CrossValidated.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This would also be on-topic at [DataScience.SE]. In fact, my answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/80679/103488) might be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

For most applications inference time is much more important than training time. The general idea is that you do training once, and even if it took 4 days, you can evaluate new instances within fractions of a second so the training time was well invested.

For (most) non learning methods training time and inference time are the same so the time complexity matters a lot.

Comment: And for many of the (scientific) applications I have some familiarity with, even a four-day training time is negligible compared to the time required to collect, preprocess and curate the input data. I'd guess many CS works may take the existence of a prepared dataset for granted, but it can be an important practical consideration for non-CS-centric ML papers.

Answer (score 0):

"Not significant" is too strong. But note that there is theoretical (worst case, usually) and practical time complexity. Many problems can be solved with "inefficient" algorithms if the worst case is unlikely. And complexity is most important for problems that need to be solved frequently on different data, making it more likely that you hit a worst case.

Also, even an exponential time algorithm can be very useful if the 'size' of the inputs can be guaranteed small so that the exponent is small. I once built such an algorithm into a product. One person freaked out, but it worked in practice.

Additionally, if you can choose from among many algorithms it may be best to choose the efficient one (other things being equal), but in the case of few choices you use what you have if you want the answers.

Finally, some problems are so important to answer that in order to get *good* answers you may have to just use an inefficient algorithm. Deep learning may be one of these problems, since many existing approaches seem to come up with scary conclusions.

So, important, yes. But not the only consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this statement is completely true. There are many papers which mention about the run time in Deep learning. Interestingly, there are quite few papers out there analysing run times for "Greener deep learning".

Also, another reason why a good chunk of paper do not have run times mentioned is because it isn't important to the task. Most, if not all times, choosing the right metric to evaluate one's model is of utmost importance and the run time not affecting the overall objective of the problem is quite common. Hence it is not included.

But all papers which have GitHub repos generally mention the runtime and computer resources required to run their code.